# Count dimension member based on other dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to define a measure that will count dimension members by other dimension and add it as a measure on the cube. 
 Should I create a new measure group with a count of the attribute of dimension or it's better to create a calculated member?

Example on adventureworks: count products by ProductCategory

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Number of Products] AS
Count(Existing
[Product].[Product].[Product].Members
)
SELECT
[Measures].[Number of Products] on 0,
{[Product].[Category].Members} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: what is the question? `Count(Existing` is the answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given details, but my guess is that your current code will return the count of all products, repeated for each Product Category.

I don't have a working copy of Adventureworks to hand, but if Product is a level one level below Product Category in hierarchy "ProductHierarchy" on the Product dimension, this should work:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Number of Products] AS
Count([Product].[ProductHierarchy].CurrentMember.Descendants)
SELECT
[Measures].[Number of Products] ON 0,
{[Product].[Category].Members} ON 1
FROM [Adventure WOrks]
```

Comment: I edit the question above using 'Existing', where I get the calculation I want. How will I define a count of attribute members based on other dimension members?

Comment: Don't understand.  EXISTING is a way to get what you want (alternative to what I put in my answer).  So is there still a problem?

Comment: I reedit  the question because wasn't clear. The new measure group is connected only with 2 dimensions.That's cause there is not any FK to the other dimensions?